# How to overlay a view over the contents of a SwiftUI list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm curious, is there a way to overlay a view spanning over all the *contents* of a `List`? For instance, I'd like to use a `Shape` view to draw a big X over the contents.

Note, the X would scroll with the contents. If the contents are larger than the `List` then when the X would only be partially visible, with the hidden parts becoming visible exactly as the underlying contents are scrolled into view.

Here's some code to give us a scenario to work with:

```swift
struct OverlayList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<50) { index in
                Text("Item \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make things even clearer, here's how I would be able to solve it if I were working with a `VStack` inside a `ScrollView`, so I have access to the part I want to put in an overlay:

```swift
struct Xshape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: rect.origin)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.width, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height))
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.width, y: rect.origin.y))

        return path
    }
}

struct OverlayVStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(1..<50) { index in
                    Text("Item \(index)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .overlay {
                Xshape()
                    .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what the results of that look like:

[image]

Comment: It's kind of clunky and there's probably a better solution, but you could 1. set the size of the X by keeping track of how many list elements are selected (i.e. 10 points larger for each element or something), and 2. use a `GeometryReader` (around the list) to get the position of one or all of the X-ed out elements and position your X accordingly as an overlay.